# Emulate dreampie in ipython

Tags: python, ipython

Dreampie is an alternative Python shell, just like IPython.

Its main selling point is the interface, split in *history box* and *code box*. You type in the code box and your code isn't messed up with outputs from the previous commands.

Unfortunately, it isn't a CLI application and it's more difficult to use over SSH. Moreover IPython embedding capabilities are far superior.

Is it possible to emulate this behaviour using IPython?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, you can use the grate IPython notebook.

In the regular-CLI ipython, you can not split the screen, but you can use %edit magic in order to enter multi-line text, or edit previews line,

```py
 In [2]: %edit #VIM, or other editor, opens and let you edit your code. 
 IPython will make a temporary file named: /tmp/ipython_edit_GHc1Wg.py
 Editing... done. Executing edited code...
 Out[2]: 'def hello():\n    print "hello world"\n' #This is the code I entered in VIM

 In [3]: hello()
 hello world

 In [4]: %edit _2  #I repoened VIM and ask it to reedit the stuff in the ouput of line [2]
 IPython will make a temporary file named: /tmp/ipython_edit_k7l0Wc.py
 Editing... done. Executing edited code...
 Out[4]: 'def hello():\n    print "godbye world"\n'

 In [5]: hello()
 godbye world
```

---

Another option is using **VIM-Ipython** (https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython) where you can type text in VIM, select part of the code and execute it in IPython-shell window inside VIM.

Comment: Thank you, Ronen. Unfortunately, `%edit` is not an option since I can't see the output while typing.

Answer (score 0):

The ipython notebook lets you write code in blocks, much like Dreampie, only executing the code when it's ready. You can also go back and edit previous commands etc, as well as embed matplotlib graphs. There's a video demonstration at http://ipython.org/notebook.html.

You can use them over SSH by opening a local tunnel (http://wisdomthroughknowledge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/accessing-ipython-notebook-remotely.html). Whether it's fast enough really depends on your connection.

The notebook has really come into its own from ipython version 1.0.

Comment: Notebook is not embeddable and embedding is for me a "killer feature". However, thank you Pascal :)